# integrate react into the wordpress

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I have a Wordpress site using a generic theme. I made React app I would like to use as a frontpage of my site. Already collected data using REST API. How can I integrate my bundle.js into existing Wordpress page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use shortcode like this **[my_shortcode]** in some wordpress page.

Then you need to implement it in your plugin (or new plugin if you have no plugins).

just add the following

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_handler' );
```

In your **my_shortcode_handler** you can serve the **html,js,css** of your React App
By using some WP functions like:

```
wp_enqueue_style
wp_enqueue_script
```

Comment: Thanks! Managed to do it by making a new plugin.